# Showing max of 10 available products

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

I know i can limit the loop but need to display a max of 10 if they are available...

```
$.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
   console.log(item.available);
   //console.log(data.results_count);
   if(item.available == true) {
       var link = $('<a></a>').attr('href', item.url);
           link.append('<span class="thumbnail"><img src="' + item.thumbnail + '" /></span>');
           link.append('<span class="title">' + item.title + '</span>');
           link.wrap('<li></li>');
       resultsList.append(link.parent());
    }
});
```

Little new to JS so unsure how to do this, at the moment i only show if item is available but just want to display a maximum of 10 if thats possible.

Comment: `if ($("a", resultsList).length) >= 10) return;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep a count of how many available ones you've already displayed, and don't allow it to go over 10. There's nothing JS-specific about this really, it's a general logical concept, but here's the JS implementation:

```
var AvailableItemCount = 0; //count of already displayed items

$.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
  console.log(item.available);
  //console.log(data.results_count);

  if(item.available == true && AvailableItemCount < 10) { //check that we haven't already displayed 10 items
    var link = $('<a></a>').attr('href', item.url);
    link.append('<span class="thumbnail"><img src="' + item.thumbnail + '" /></span>');
    link.append('<span class="title">' + item.title + '</span>');
    link.wrap('<li></li>');
    resultsList.append(link.parent());
    AvailableItemCount++; //increment the count of displayed available items
  }

  if (AvailableItemCount >= 10) { return false; } //don't waste time looping once we've displayed 10 items
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0;
$.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
  console.log(item.available);
  if(count >= 10) break;
  //console.log(data.results_count);
   if(item.available == true) {
     count++;
      var link = $('<a></a>').attr('href', item.url);
       link.append('<span class="thumbnail"><img src="' + item.thumbnail + '" /></span>');
       link.append('<span class="title">' + item.title + '</span>');
       link.wrap('<li></li>');
       resultsList.append(link.parent());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a counter, and return from the each if you reached the limit.

```
var counter = 0;
$.each(data.results, function(index, item) {
   if(item.available == true) {
      counter++;
      //Your other code
   } 
   if (counter >= 10) {
      return;
   }
});
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Damn, it works... Undeleted it, please update to answer to allow me to accept.

Answer (score 0):

you can use slice function

```
 $.each(data.results.slice(0,10), function(index, item) {
   console.log(item.available);
   //console.log(data.results_count);
   if(item.available == true) {
       var link = $('<a></a>').attr('href', item.url);
           link.append('<span class="thumbnail"><img src="' + item.thumbnail + '" /></span>');
           link.append('<span class="title">' + item.title + '</span>');
           link.wrap('<li></li>');
       resultsList.append(link.parent());
    }
});
```